# Convert String of OrderedDict to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ordereddict

Previously, I want to create a simple string `OrderedDict` conversion to `json` output. 
Actually we can just use the `json.dumps` when it input as `OrderedDict`, e.g:

```
>>> json.dumps([OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])])
'[{"abc": 1}]'
>>>
```

but the problem is it input as a `string` of `OrderedDict`, `string` list of `OrderedDict` or mybe just a `string` of dict/list. *It also should support with recursive values, bytes input `{b'a': 1}` & unicode `{u'a': 1}`.*

> Here, I'm not using `eval` because [Eval is really dangerous to use](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Here is some example inputs & expected outputs:

Type 1, a single string `OrderedDict`;

```
input = "OrderedDict({'abc': 1})"
output = {"abc": 1}
```

Type 2, a single string `OrderedDict` with recursive values:

```
input = "OrderedDict([('abc', OrderedDict([('def', 2)]))])"
output = {"abc": {"def": 2}}
```

Type 3, a string dict with a single value of `OrderedDict`:

```
input = "{'key': OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])}"
output = {"key": {"abc": 1}}
```

Type 4, a string list with `OrderedDict` values:

```
input = "[OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])]"
output = [{"abc": 1}]
```

Type 5, just a string dict:

```
input = "{'abc': 1}"
output = {"abc": 1}
```

Type 6, just a string of list:

```
input = "[{'abc': 1}]"
output = [{"abc": 1}]
```

Type 7, using `unicode` or `bytes`:

```
input = "{u'abc': 1}"
output = {"abc": 1}

input = "{b'abc': 1}"
output = {"abc": 1}
```

Comment: Why do you have such strings?

Comment: @KellyBundy because the input is coming from html `form`. So the given input can be have differents format.

Comment: You mean a user typed in that string? Or it somehow got produced by some framework/code, which probably shouldn't have done that?

Comment: @KellyBundy so, basicly the user will put his exact `OrderedDict` code to the html form (like this comment form), but in fact our backend code, we will get it value as string right?

Comment: Hmm... what kind of website is that?

Comment: @KellyBundy that's why I want to create this, because it really usefull for python developers for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there's a closer solution to your problem. From what I know, you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) but you would need to manually convert the 2-item tuples to dict.

```
import ast

for the_input in [
    "OrderedDict({'abc': 1})",
    "OrderedDict([('abc', OrderedDict([('def', 2)]))])",
    "{'key': OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])}",
    "[OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])]",
    "{'abc': 1}",
    "[{'abc': 1}]",
    "{u'abc': 1}",
    "{b'abc': 1}",
]:
    the_input = the_input.replace("OrderedDict", "")
    the_output = ast.literal_eval(the_input)
    print(type(the_output), the_output)
```

Output

```
<class 'dict'> {'abc': 1}
<class 'list'> [('abc', [('def', 2)])]
<class 'dict'> {'key': [('abc', 1)]}
<class 'list'> [[('abc', 1)]]
<class 'dict'> {'abc': 1}
<class 'list'> [{'abc': 1}]
<class 'dict'> {'abc': 1}
<class 'dict'> {b'abc': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use a parser.

This clearly is not an easy fix, but if you are already familiar with parsing it could definitely be applied here.

There are tons of different existing parsers for Python, for the example let's say you choose PLY (not the fanciest but considering what you want to do it is enough)

Parsing requires first that you tokenize your text. Here you only need a handful of tokens:

```
import ply.lex as lex

tokens = (LPAREN, RPAREN, ORDEREDDICT, TEXT)
t_LPAREN = "("
t_RPAREN = ")"
t_ORDEREDDICT = "OrderedDict"
t_TEXT = r'(?:(?!(OrderedDict|\(|\))).)+'

lexer = lex.lex()
```

This means that the parser will consider that the "(" symbol is a "LPAREN" (left-parenthesis), the ")" symbol a "RPAREN", and the sequence "OrderedDict" a special thing. Other sequences of symbols (that do not contain parenthesis or the sequence "OrderedDict") will be considered to be TEXT.

As an example, "{'key': OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])}" at this point would be converted to:
TEXT({'key': ), ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, TEXT([), LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})
You can test it with:

```
lexer.input("{'key': OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])}")
```

Then the actual parsing can take place:

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
import json

def p_ordereddict(p):
    'data : ORDEREDDICT LPAREN data RPAREN'
    p[0] = json.dumps(OrderedDict(json.loads(p[3])))

def p_otherparenthesis(p):
    'data : LPAREN data RPAREN'
    p[0] = p[1]+p[2]+p[3]

def p_concat(p):
    'data : data data'
    p[0] = p[1]+p[2]

def p_texttodata(p):
    'data : TEXT'
    p[0] = p[1]

parser = yacc.yacc()
```

This should be read as three rules:

- If I see the "ORDEREDDICT" token, I have to look for a left parenthesis right after, then something called "data", then a closing right parenthesis. The whole thing is then considered "data" itself, and its value is the one of the data we had between parenthesis but passed through the "OrderedDict" operator.
- If I see a left parenthesis (and I am not in the previous case), I need to identify a "data" sequence and a closing right parenthesis. The whole thing is itself data.
- If I see several data next to one another I can concatenate them
- Something tagged as TEXT is data

To take back our previous example:

"{'key': OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])}"

was converted to:

TEXT({'key': ), ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, TEXT([), LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

The parser starts from the left, and finds a TEXT token. The only rule that cares about leading TEXT tokens is the 4th and according to this rule the token becomes data:

data({'key': ), ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, TEXT([), LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

Now we have a leading data object. The rule that defines what should happen is the 3rd one: we have to look further for an other data object:

data({'key': ), (we are here now, looking for data) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, TEXT([), LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

the ORDEREDDICT token is handled by the 1st rule, so it becomes:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we are here, looking for data and then RPAREN) TEXT([), LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

Then, TEXT([) is identified as data per the 4th rule:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we are here, looking for data and then RPAREN) data([), LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

what follows data([) is not RPAREN, but that's not a problem since the 3rd rule means a succession of data objects can be concatenated:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([), (we are here, looking for data) LPAREN, TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

The 2nd rule applies:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([), (we expect data here) LPAREN, (we are here, looking for data and then RPAREN) TEXT('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

4th rule:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([), (we expect data here) LPAREN, (we are here, looking for data and then RPAREN) data('abc', 1), RPAREN, TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

we have the data+RPAREN sequence we were looking for, so we can wrap that up with 2nd rule:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([), (we are here, we expect data here) data(('abc', 1)), TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

now we have the data to apply 3rd rule:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we are here, we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([('abc', 1)), TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

we can't apply 1st rule yet. You should get the idea so I am just writing the steps from now on:

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([('abc', 1)), (we are here, looking for data) TEXT(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([('abc', 1)), (we are here, looking for data) data(]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

data({'key': ), (we expect data here) ORDEREDDICT, LPAREN, (we are here, we expect data and then RPAREN here) data([('abc', 1)]), RPAREN, TEXT(})

data({'key': ), (we are here, we expect data here) data({'abc':1}), TEXT(})

(we are here) data({'key': {'abc':1}), TEXT(})

data({'key': {'abc':1}), (we are here, looking for data) TEXT(})

data({'key': {'abc':1}), (we are here, looking for data) data(})

data({'key': {'abc':1}})

---

Finally, to use your parser, simply call its "parse" method. For example:

```
example = "{'key': OrderedDict([('abc', 1)])}"
parsed = parser.parse(example, lexer=lexer)
print(parsed)
```